# Print text when there are no prime numbers between two integers python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to print the words "No Prime between the numbers" if there aren't prime numbers between the entered integers. For example, if a user inputs 8 and 10, there aren't any prime numbers, so the message above should be printed. 
However, I'm having a hard time placing the print statement in my code:

```
num_1 = int(input("Enter your first number: "));
num_2 = int(input("Enter your second number: "));
num_3 = 0

if num_2 > num_1:
    num_3 = num_1
    num_1 = num_2
    num_2 = num_3

delim_list = [":","!",","]
blank_list = []
for num in range(num_3, num_1):
    if num > 1:
            for i in range(2,num):
                if (num%i) == 0:
                    break 

            else:
                blank_list.append(str(num) + delim_list[len(blank_list)%3])

blank_list = "".join(blank_list)
print("No Prime between the numbers")
print(blank_list[:-1])
```

My output will print "No Prime numbers between the numbers" and then print the prime numbers:

```
Enter your first number:  1
Enter your second number:  10
No Prime between the numbers
2:3!5,7
```

Comment: Your print statement does not have any conditions around it, it will be printed at all times. You can write an if condition before the print and check if the array is empty before printing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your array is empty before trying to print the message

```
if not blank_list:
    print("No Prime between the numbers")
```